# EF 6.1 IDbCommandTreeInterceptor to edit insertion doesn't upate resulting entity properties

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, code-first

Based on an article I found [here](http://xabikos.com/multitenant/application%20design/software%20as%20a%20service/2014/11/18/create-a-multitenant-application-with-entity-framework-code-first---part-2.html) I implemented a multi-tenant IDbCommandInterceptor.
I noticed that the implementation doesn't update the values on the model that I insert as a part of the IDbCommandInterceptor. My hope is to fix this.

I use the interceptor to add correct values for the following properties on the base model:

- EntityTenantId
- Created
- CreatedBy

Additionally I change the DbInsertCommandTree to use a DbNewInstanceExpression that includes those fields, aside from the EntityId (Identity) & Timestamp.

Eventhough the 3 extra fields I add are queried correctly, only the database generated fields (EntityId & Timestamp) are updated in the model.

**Question:**
Does anybody have a clue as to how I can get EF to update my model, after an insertion, for fields that do not normally fall under the category of database generated?
In other words, after calling SaveChanges() to save a new entity, that entity will have updated property values for EntityId & Timestamp. How can I make sure the 3 extra properties are updated on the model instance as well?

Unit test:

```
using (new MockRuntimeContext(ConstantPrincipals.DefaultTestUser))
            {
                using (var dbContext = new EndUserDbContext(TestConstants.EndUserDatabaseName))
                {
                    var newPerson = dbContext.Persons.Create();
                    newPerson.FirstName = "InsertEntityFname";
                    newPerson.LastName = "InsertEntityLname";
                    newPerson.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(365*29));

                    dbContext.Persons.Add(newPerson);
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();

                    Assert.AreNotEqual(newPerson.EntityId, Guid.Empty);
                    //Fails.. but it's value in the database is correct.
                    Assert.AreEqual(newPerson.EntityTenantId, RuntimeContext.GetCurrentTenantIdForDataInsertion());
                    //Fails.. but it's value in the database is correct.
                    Assert.AreEqual(newPerson.EntityCreatedBy, RuntimeContext.GetAuthenticatedUserId());
                    //Fails.. but it's value in the database is correct.
                    Assert.AreNotEqual(newPerson.EntityCreated, null);
                }
            }
```

Base model:

```
public class BaseEntity : ITenantAwareEntity, ISoftDeleteEntity, ITimestampEntity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Key]
    public  Guid EntityId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EntityCreated { get; private set; }


    public virtual Guid EntityCreatedBy { get; private set; }

    public virtual DateTime? EntityUpdated { get; private set; }

    public virtual Guid? EntityUpdatedBy { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// if the EntityTenantId is set the entity is scoped towards the tenant corresponding to the
    /// tenant with that ID.
    /// If the EntityTenantId is not set, the entity is available to everybody.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Guid? EntityTenantId { get; private set; }

    public virtual bool EntityIsDeleted { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// An entity timestamp for row version concurrency checks.
    /// </summary>
    [Timestamp]
    public virtual byte[] EntityTimeStamp { get; private set; }
```

Resulting insertion Query:

```
"DECLARE @generated_keys table([EntityId] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [Actor].[Persons]([FirstName], [LastName], [DateOfBirth_ValueLong], [PlaceofBirth], [Comment], [ExternalReference], [EntityUpdated], [EntityUpdatedBy], [EntityIsDeleted], [CountryOfOrigin_EntityId], [Language_EntityId], [MaritalStatus_EntityId], [Nationality_EntityId], [OccupationType_EntityId], [Sex_EntityId], [EntityTenantId], [EntityCreatedBy], [EntityCreated])\r\nOUTPUT inserted.[EntityId] INTO @generated_keys\r\nVALUES (@0, @1, @2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, @3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, @4, @5, @6)
SELECT t.[EntityId], t.[EntityTimeStamp], t.[EntityTenantId], t.[EntityCreatedBy], t.[EntityCreated]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [Actor].[Persons] AS t ON g.[EntityId] = t.[EntityId]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0"
```

Here is the interceptor I use (it is called and all properties are set to values as specified by the interceptor.

```
public class TenantCommandTreeInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
    {
        private readonly MultiTenantAccessFacilitator _multiTenantAccessFacilitator;

        public TenantCommandTreeInterceptor(MultiTenantAccessFacilitator multiTenantAccessFacilitator)
        {
            _multiTenantAccessFacilitator = multiTenantAccessFacilitator;
        }

        public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
        {
            if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace != DataSpace.SSpace) return;

            // Check that there is an authenticated user in this context
            var identity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            if (identity == null || identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
            {
                return;
            }
            var userIdclaim = identity.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            if (userIdclaim == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var currentUserIdExctractedFromClaimsPrincipal = Guid.Parse(userIdclaim.Value);

            if (interceptionContext.Result.CommandTreeKind == DbCommandTreeKind.Insert)
            {
                InterceptInsertStatement(interceptionContext, currentUserIdExctractedFromClaimsPrincipal);
                return;
            }
            else if (interceptionContext.Result.CommandTreeKind == DbCommandTreeKind.Update)
            {

                InterceptUpdateCommand(interceptionContext, currentUserIdExctractedFromClaimsPrincipal);
                return;
            }
            else if(interceptionContext.Result.CommandTreeKind == DbCommandTreeKind.Query)
            {
                var queryCommand = interceptionContext.Result as DbQueryCommandTree;
                if (queryCommand != null)
                {
                    var newQuery =
                        queryCommand.Query.Accept(
                            new TenantSelectionFilterQueryVisitor(_multiTenantAccessFacilitator));
                    interceptionContext.Result = new DbQueryCommandTree(
                        queryCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
                        queryCommand.DataSpace,
                        newQuery);
                    return;

                }
            }
        }

        private void InterceptUpdateCommand(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
            Guid currentUserIdExctractedFromClaimsPrincipal)
        {
            var updateCommand = interceptionContext.Result as DbUpdateCommandTree;

            List<DbSetClause> replacedSetClause = new List<DbSetClause>();
            List<DbSetClause> autoSetClause = new List<DbSetClause>();

            //UpdatedBy
            var column = nameof(BaseEntity.EntityUpdatedBy);
            DbSetClause existingSetClause, newClause;
            DbExpression newValue =
                DbExpression.FromGuid(currentUserIdExctractedFromClaimsPrincipal);

            if (ChangeUpdateSetClause(column, newValue, updateCommand, out newClause, out existingSetClause))
            {
                autoSetClause.Add(newClause);
                if (existingSetClause != null)
                {
                    replacedSetClause.Add(existingSetClause);
                }
            }

            //Updated
            column = nameof(BaseEntity.EntityUpdated);
            newValue = DbExpression.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);

            if (ChangeUpdateSetClause(column, newValue, updateCommand, out newClause, out existingSetClause))
            {
                autoSetClause.Add(newClause);
                if (existingSetClause != null)
                {
                    replacedSetClause.Add(existingSetClause);
                }
            }

            if (autoSetClause.Count > 0)
            {
                // Remove clauses
                var filteredSetClauses = updateCommand.SetClauses.Cast<DbSetClause>()
                    .Where(sc => !replacedSetClause.Contains(sc))
                    .ToList();
                Debug.Assert(filteredSetClauses.Count == updateCommand.SetClauses.Count - replacedSetClause.Count);

                //add new clauses
                filteredSetClauses.AddRange(autoSetClause);

                // Construct the final clauses, object representation of sql insert command values
                var finalUpdateSetClauses =
                    new ReadOnlyCollection<DbModificationClause>(new List<DbModificationClause>(filteredSetClauses));

                var newUpdateCommand = new DbInsertCommandTree(
                    updateCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
                    updateCommand.DataSpace,
                    updateCommand.Target,
                    finalUpdateSetClauses,
                    updateCommand.Returning);

                interceptionContext.Result = newUpdateCommand;
            }
        }

        private void InterceptInsertStatement(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
            Guid currentUserIdExctractedFromClaimsPrincipal)
        {
            var insertCommand = interceptionContext.Result as DbInsertCommandTree;

            List<DbSetClause> replacedSetClause = new List<DbSetClause>();
            List<DbSetClause> autoSetClause = new List<DbSetClause>();

            //TENANT AWARE
            var column = nameof(ITenantAwareEntity.EntityTenantId);
            DbSetClause existingSetClause, newClause;
            DbExpression newValue = DbExpression.FromGuid(_multiTenantAccessFacilitator.GetCurrentTenantIdForDataInsertion());

            if (ChangeInsertSetClause(column, newValue, insertCommand, out newClause, out existingSetClause))
            {
                autoSetClause.Add(newClause);
                replacedSetClause.Add(existingSetClause);
            }

            //CreatedBy
            column = nameof(BaseEntity.EntityCreatedBy);
            newValue = DbExpression.FromGuid(currentUserIdExctractedFromClaimsPrincipal);
            if (ChangeInsertSetClause(column, newValue, insertCommand, out newClause, out existingSetClause))
            {
                autoSetClause.Add(newClause);
                replacedSetClause.Add(existingSetClause);
            }

            //Created
            column = nameof(BaseEntity.EntityCreated);
            newValue = DbExpression.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
            if (ChangeInsertSetClause(column, newValue, insertCommand, out newClause, out existingSetClause))
            {
                autoSetClause.Add(newClause);
                if (existingSetClause != null)
                {
                    replacedSetClause.Add(existingSetClause);
                }
            }

            Debug.Assert(autoSetClause.Count == replacedSetClause.Count);

            if (autoSetClause.Count > 0)
            {
                // Remove clauses
                var filteredSetClauses = insertCommand.SetClauses.Cast<DbSetClause>()
                    .Where(sc => !replacedSetClause.Contains(sc))
                    .ToList();
                Debug.Assert(filteredSetClauses.Count == insertCommand.SetClauses.Count - replacedSetClause.Count);

                //add new clauses
                filteredSetClauses.AddRange(autoSetClause);

                // Construct the final clauses, object representation of sql insert command values
                var finalSetClauses =
                    new ReadOnlyCollection<DbModificationClause>(new List<DbModificationClause>(filteredSetClauses));

                // construct a new returning
                var existingNewInstanceExpression = insertCommand.Returning as DbNewInstanceExpression;
                DbNewInstanceExpression newInstanceAfterInsert = null;
                if (existingNewInstanceExpression != null)
                {
                    var existingRowType = existingNewInstanceExpression.ResultType.EdmType as RowType;
                    //include existing.
                    var edmProperties = new List<EdmProperty>(existingRowType.Properties);

                    foreach (var dbSetClause in autoSetClause)
                    {
                        var propertyExpression = (dbSetClause.Property as DbPropertyExpression);
                        if (propertyExpression != null)
                        {
                            if (edmProperties.All(a => a.Name != propertyExpression.Property.Name))
                            {
                                var edmProperty = propertyExpression.Property.DeclaringType.Members
                                    .OfType<EdmProperty>()
                                    .First(p => p.Name == propertyExpression.Property.Name);
                                edmProperties.Add(edmProperty);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    var rowType = RowType.Create(edmProperties, null);
                    List<DbExpression> arguments = new List<DbExpression>(existingNewInstanceExpression.Arguments);
                    foreach (var dbSetClause in autoSetClause)
                    {
                        var variableReference = DbExpressionBuilder.Variable(insertCommand.Target.VariableType,
                            insertCommand.Target.VariableName);
                        // Create the property to which will assign the correct value
                        var property = DbExpressionBuilder.Property(variableReference,
                            (dbSetClause.Property as DbPropertyExpression).Property.Name);

                        arguments.Add(property);
                    }


                    newInstanceAfterInsert =
                        DbExpressionBuilder.New(TypeUsage.Create(rowType, insertCommand.Returning.ResultType.Facets), arguments);
                }

                var newInsertCommand = new DbInsertCommandTree(
                    insertCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
                    insertCommand.DataSpace,
                    insertCommand.Target, finalSetClauses, newInstanceAfterInsert);

                interceptionContext.Result = newInsertCommand;
            }
        }

        private bool ChangeInsertSetClause(string column, DbExpression newValueToSetToDb, DbInsertCommandTree insertCommand, out DbSetClause newSetClause, out DbSetClause existingSetClause)
        {
            newSetClause = existingSetClause = null;
            existingSetClause = insertCommand.SetClauses.OfType<DbSetClause>().SingleOrDefault(p => (p.Property as DbPropertyExpression).Property.Name == column);



            if (existingSetClause != null)
            {
                // Create the variable reference in order to create the property
                var variableReference = DbExpressionBuilder.Variable(insertCommand.Target.VariableType,
                    insertCommand.Target.VariableName);
                // Create the property to which will assign the correct value
                var tenantProperty = DbExpressionBuilder.Property(variableReference, column);
                // Create the set clause, object representation of sql insert command
                newSetClause =
                    DbExpressionBuilder.SetClause(tenantProperty, newValueToSetToDb);
            }
            return newSetClause != null;
        }
        private bool ChangeUpdateSetClause(string column, DbExpression newValueToSetToDb, DbUpdateCommandTree updateCommand, out DbSetClause newSetClause, out DbSetClause existingSetClause)
        {
            newSetClause = existingSetClause = null;
            existingSetClause = updateCommand.SetClauses.OfType<DbSetClause>().SingleOrDefault(p => (p.Property as DbPropertyExpression).Property.Name == column);



            if (existingSetClause != null)
            {
                // Create the variable reference in order to create the property
                var variableReference = DbExpressionBuilder.Variable(updateCommand.Target.VariableType,
                    updateCommand.Target.VariableName);
                // Create the property to which will assign the correct value
                var tenantProperty = DbExpressionBuilder.Property(variableReference, column);
                // Create the set clause, object representation of sql insert command
                newSetClause =
                    DbExpressionBuilder.SetClause(tenantProperty, newValueToSetToDb);
            }
            return newSetClause != null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @bubi thx for taking the time. Added the interceptor code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you can simplify the code because you are using Guids as Ids so they are unique regardless of tenant.

For sure in insert you can use the original returning command (the command that EF needs to retrieve the just inserted entity).
I simplyfied your code removing update and delete. Actually I think you don't need them as well (the Guids are still unique independently from the tenant anyway you can restore them).

I also added a class without your base class.
Here the code

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    private readonly IDbInterceptor _dbTreeInterceptor;

    public Context(DbConnection connection)
        : base(connection, false)
    {
        // NOT THE RIGHT PLACE TO DO THIS!!!
        _dbTreeInterceptor = new TenantCommandTreeInterceptor();
        DbInterception.Add(_dbTreeInterceptor);
    }

    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        DbInterception.Remove(_dbTreeInterceptor);

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}

public class TenantCommandTreeInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
{
    public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace != DataSpace.SSpace) return;

        if (interceptionContext.Result.CommandTreeKind == DbCommandTreeKind.Insert)
            InterceptInsertStatement(interceptionContext);
    }

    private void InterceptInsertStatement(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        var insertCommand = interceptionContext.Result as DbInsertCommandTree;

        List<DbSetClause> replacedSetClause = new List<DbSetClause>();
        List<DbSetClause> autoSetClause = new List<DbSetClause>();

        //TENANT AWARE
        string column = "TenantId";
        DbSetClause existingSetClause;
        DbSetClause  newClause;
        DbExpression newValue = "JustMe"; // Here we should insert the right value

        if (ChangeInsertSetClause(column, newValue, insertCommand, out newClause, out existingSetClause))
        {
            autoSetClause.Add(newClause);
            replacedSetClause.Add(existingSetClause);
        }

        Debug.Assert(autoSetClause.Count == replacedSetClause.Count);

        if (autoSetClause.Count > 0)
        {
            // Remove clauses
            var filteredSetClauses = insertCommand.SetClauses.Cast<DbSetClause>()
                .Where(sc => !replacedSetClause.Contains(sc))
                .ToList();
            Debug.Assert(filteredSetClauses.Count == insertCommand.SetClauses.Count - replacedSetClause.Count);

            //add new clauses
            filteredSetClauses.AddRange(autoSetClause);

            // Construct the final clauses, object representation of sql insert command values
            var finalSetClauses =
                new ReadOnlyCollection<DbModificationClause>(new List<DbModificationClause>(filteredSetClauses));

            // In insert probably you can avoid to change the newInstanceAfterInsert because you are using a Guid for the entity ID that is always unique (it does not matter the tenant). 

            var newInsertCommand = new DbInsertCommandTree(
                insertCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
                insertCommand.DataSpace,
                insertCommand.Target, 
                finalSetClauses, 
                insertCommand.Returning);

            interceptionContext.Result = newInsertCommand;
        }
    }

    private bool ChangeInsertSetClause(string column, DbExpression newValueToSetToDb, DbInsertCommandTree insertCommand, out DbSetClause newSetClause, out DbSetClause existingSetClause)
    {
        newSetClause = null;
        existingSetClause = insertCommand.SetClauses.
            OfType<DbSetClause>().SingleOrDefault(p => (p.Property as DbPropertyExpression).Property.Name == column);



        if (existingSetClause != null)
        {
            // Create the variable reference in order to create the property
            var variableReference = DbExpressionBuilder.Variable(insertCommand.Target.VariableType,
                insertCommand.Target.VariableName);
            // Create the property to which will assign the correct value
            var tenantProperty = DbExpressionBuilder.Property(variableReference, column);
            // Create the set clause, object representation of sql insert command
            newSetClause =
                DbExpressionBuilder.SetClause(tenantProperty, newValueToSetToDb);
        }
        return newSetClause != null;
    }
}


static class Test
{
    public static void Run(DbConnection connection)
    {

        using (Context context = new Context(connection))
        {
            context.MyEntities.Add(new MyEntity()
            {
                Description = "My first message"
            });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }



    }
}
```

Calling Test.Run this is the query that EF runs against database.

```
insert into [MyEntities]([Description], [TenantId])
values (@p0, @p1);
select [Id]
from [MyEntities]
where [Id] = @@identity
@p0 = My first message
@p1 = JustMe
```

Creating a base class with Id and TenantId works as well.

So, the best thing in your case could be that you start simplyfing as I did then add the parts that you need.

**EDIT**
This works but the inserted entity is not updated with the TenantId.

To solve the problem you can set the field as database generated (so EF will read it) but generate it in the interceptor.
Here the example but to run it you need to fix the TODO:
If you'd like to test it you can put a breakpoint and avoid the interception of insert in the migration table.

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public string TenantId { get; set; }

}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    private readonly IDbInterceptor _dbTreeInterceptor;

    public Context(DbConnection connection)
        : base(connection, false)
    {
        // NOT THE RIGHT PLACE TO DO THIS!!!
        _dbTreeInterceptor = new TenantCommandTreeInterceptor();
        DbInterception.Add(_dbTreeInterceptor);
    }

    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        DbInterception.Remove(_dbTreeInterceptor);

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}




public class TenantCommandTreeInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
{
    public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace != DataSpace.SSpace) return;

        if (interceptionContext.Result.CommandTreeKind == DbCommandTreeKind.Insert)
            InterceptInsertStatement(interceptionContext);
    }

    private void InterceptInsertStatement(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        var insertCommand = interceptionContext.Result as DbInsertCommandTree;

        List<DbModificationClause> finalSetClauses = new List<DbModificationClause>((IEnumerable<DbModificationClause>)insertCommand.SetClauses);

        //TENANT AWARE
        string column = "TenantId";
        DbExpression newValue = "JustMe"; // Here we should insert the right value


        // TODO: Need to check if this entity is a Multitenant entity in the right way
        // You can use the attribute like in the original sample


        finalSetClauses.Add(
            GetInsertSetClause(column, newValue, insertCommand));

        // Construct the final clauses, object representation of sql insert command values

        // In insert probably you can avoid to change the newInstanceAfterInsert because you are using a Guid for the entity ID that is always unique (it does not matter the tenant). 

        var newInsertCommand = new DbInsertCommandTree(
            insertCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
            insertCommand.DataSpace,
            insertCommand.Target,
            new ReadOnlyCollection<DbModificationClause>(finalSetClauses),
            insertCommand.Returning);

        interceptionContext.Result = newInsertCommand;
    }

    private DbSetClause GetInsertSetClause(string column, DbExpression newValueToSetToDb, DbInsertCommandTree insertCommand)
    {
        // Create the variable reference in order to create the property
        DbVariableReferenceExpression variableReference = DbExpressionBuilder.Variable(insertCommand.Target.VariableType,
            insertCommand.Target.VariableName);
        // Create the property to which will assign the correct value
        DbPropertyExpression tenantProperty = DbExpressionBuilder.Property(variableReference, column);
        // Create the set clause, object representation of sql insert command
        DbSetClause newSetClause = DbExpressionBuilder.SetClause(tenantProperty, newValueToSetToDb);
        return newSetClause;
    }
}

    public static void Run(DbConnection connection)
    {

        using (Context context = new Context(connection))
        {
            MyEntity myNewEntity;

            context.MyEntities.Add(myNewEntity = new MyEntity()
            {
                Description = "My first message"
            });
            context.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", myNewEntity.Id, myNewEntity.TenantId);

        }



    }
```

Comment: Well, the interception works fine for me (although I must admit the code I posted is bloated). 
The problem is what follows. After context.SaveChanges() the property 'TenantId' on the entity you inserted should hold the value 'JustMe'
But is isn't being updated.

Comment: If you read the query that EF runs agains the db (not the insert, the select) you can understand why :). One try is to mark TenantId as database generated but after that the provider probably (for sure the on I'm using now) does not generate the insert for the TenantId

Comment: True, but that is only a problem in your code... you left out the DbNewInstanceExpression adjustment. If you look at the sql query in my question, the updated fields are defenitly in there. Just not propagated tot the model by EF.

Comment: I update the code with TenantId retrieving but actually I'm not sure that EF will read it when the provider returns it.

Comment: @bobi It seems like entity framework only reads the results corrersponding tot the database generated columns (in my case an identity and a timestamp column). I'am hoping to get around this. Possibly by using custom entity adapters?

Comment: Actually, restoring the code, the query to retrieve the just inserted entity is ok but the EF ignore that value. About changing the materialization process I made this unclear question some times ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27100219/customize-materialization-process-in-an-entity-framework-provider